# Upgrade manager cannot find a server

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, internet, connection

My upgrade manager went zombie a long time ago. I finally decided to do something about it. It claims that I have an invalid Internet connection when I tell him to find a best suitable server on the server list. When I choose the server by myself it simply does not find any updates. Because of that I am stuck at the 12.04 version.

My Internet connection is definitely very fine, I tried at 4 different Internet sources. So where's the bug?

PS I have already tried doing this by the command line with sudo do release upgrade and all of that. The result is similar - no updates found.

Contents of `etc/apt/sources`

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ferramroberto-sopcast-oneiric.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ferramroberto-sopcast-oneiric.list.distUpgrade
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ferramroberto-sopcast-oneiric.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-talkplugin.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-talkplugin.list.distUpgrade
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-talkplugin.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-partner.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-partner.list.distUpgrade
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-partner.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-precise.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-precise.list.distUpgrade
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-precise.list.save
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-x-swat-x-updates-precise.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-x-swat-x-updates-precise.list.distUpgrade
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-x-swat-x-updates-precise.list.save
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 0):

In Software and Updates, if you disable all the other software repositories, this will allow you to receive updates.

Another way is to type in to Terminal

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

This should tell you what's available.

Comment: Read the post, I have already done that, and it did not help.